Restriction of a voronoi diagram to a plane?
Say I have a set of points $P$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Let $V = \{\mathcal{V_i}\}$  be the Voronoi diagram of $P$, where $\mathcal{V_i}$ are the Voronoi cells.
Assume we have a point $p \in P$ and assign to it a plane $H$.
Consider the interesection $V \cap H = \cup \{\mathcal{V_i}\cap H\}$. Each $\mathcal{V_i}\cap H$ is an intersection between convex sets and is therefore a convex set itself. It's not too hard to see that each $\mathcal{V_i}\cap H$ is either the empty set or a convex polygon (not necessarily closed) and that it is effectively the Voronoi diagram of a set of points in $H$.
Thus for each $\mathcal{V_i}\cap H$ that is not empty. there exists a point $p'_i$ that is the center of that cell.
Since each Voronoi cell $\mathcal{V_i}$ can be associated with a point $P$, then this implies that for each $p_i$ whose associated cell does intersect $H$ we can find its projection $p'_i$ such that the projection is the center of the restricted cell.
My question is, how can I find $p'_i$ from $p_i$.
For example, consider the easier case where the points are in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Such as in this diagram:

The points are the centers of the Voronoi cells. The red line is $H$, the "plane" (line in this case) that we are restricting the Voronoi diagram to. The black lines are the bisectors between each pair of consecutive points, as a way to sort of visualize the Voronoi diagram easily.
What we would be interested in is, how to find a projection of $A$ onto $H$ such that that projection is the center of the voronoi cell formed by the segment in between the two bisectors around $A$.

“that it is effectively the Voronoi diagram of a set of points in $H$.” why is this true?

@Pranay it is a tessellation of the plane made exclusively of convex polygons with no gaps. That's equivalent to a Voronoi diagram.

A 2D cross section through an ordinary 3D Voronoi tessellation is in general not itself an ordinary 2D Voronoi tessellation.

@JohnBarber Could you please explain? In which circumstances does it not produce a voronoi diagram?

@Makogan consider the following tessellation of the plane. The upper half plane and the two quadrants of the lower half plane. These three regions are convex and have no gaps between them. But that doesn’t make it a Voronoi tessellation. I also agree with @JohnBarber’s comment.

I guess that's true. But I also don't think you can produce those cross sections by intersecting a Voronoi diagram in $\mathbb{R}^3$.
So I am still not sure why it would not be the case. Especially since these cross sections are guaranteed to contain at least one of the points in the original cell centers.
There is a proof that shows that the intersection of a plane with a weighted voronoi diagram and a plane is a weighted voronoi diagram on that plane. So it would seem plausible that the same is true for a regular Voronoi diagram.

Maybe this will clarify it for me. Do you want $p’=p$, or can they be different?

$p'$ can be anything, as long as it is in $H$ and as long as the resulting cell border in the plane is the cross-section of the original cell with $H$. Asides from that, $p'$ is free to move within the bounds of the restricted cell, it doesn't need to be an orthogonal projection either.

Ah okay, that makes sense to me. Thanks for clarifying.
